# What are these spots on my new bamboo palm?

Tags: diseases, fungus, palm, bamboo

[image]

Hi all! I’m new to gardening and want to know what’s going on with this palm I just bought from the Home Depot. There are white spots near the roots that look like fungus to me, brown spots higher up on the stem, and, most puzzlingly, tough round black spots. I have no idea what any of these things are or the implications that they hold. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

In the South, in a coastal climate, Phyllostachys can develop brown spots on the canes due to a harmless fungus. There have also been reports in the Southeast of a disease that top kills bamboo, but nothing has been discovered as to the cause.

Source: https://www.bamboogarden.com/faq

Trim culms or treat with copper fungicide

Comment: Hi Anthony. It is unlikely that this is your site, but it is still a good practice to post a disclaimer for it.

Comment: The web link does not not help answer the question. Please edit or it could be removed